# Elasticsearch does not work when try to use with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am following the tutorial, completely new to any data bases, including Elasticsearch.

My code

```
client = Elasticsearch()
indexName = "art"
client.indices.create(index=indexName)
```

shows the following error (according to the book, it shouldn't)

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /var/folders/s5/dhdrwvbj5bs4m9nld9bp43400000gn/T/ipykernel_49947/868473428.py
> in 
> ----> 1 client = Elasticsearch()
> 2 indexName = "art"
> 3 client.indices.create(index=indexName)
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/_sync/client/**init**.py
> in **init**(self, hosts, cloud_id, api_key, basic_auth, bearer_auth,
> opaque_id, headers, connections_per_node, http_compress, verify_certs,
> ca_certs, client_cert, client_key, ssl_assert_hostname,
> ssl_assert_fingerprint, ssl_version, ssl_context, ssl_show_warn,
> transport_class, request_timeout, node_class, node_pool_class,
> randomize_nodes_in_pool, node_selector_class,
> dead_node_backoff_factor, max_dead_node_backoff, serializer,
> serializers, default_mimetype, max_retries, retry_on_status,
> retry_on_timeout, sniff_on_start, sniff_before_requests,
> sniff_on_node_failure, sniff_timeout, min_delay_between_sniffing,
> sniffed_node_callback, meta_header, timeout, randomize_hosts,
> host_info_callback, sniffer_timeout, sniff_on_connection_fail,
> http_auth, maxsize, _transport)
> 189     ) -> None:
> 190         if hosts is None and cloud_id is None and _transport is None:
> --> 191             raise ValueError("Either 'hosts' or 'cloud_id' must be specified")
> 192
> 193         if timeout is not DEFAULT:
>
> ValueError: Either 'hosts' or 'cloud_id' must be specified

When I start Elasticsearch through Terminal, I can open localhost:9200. I also have changed **#network.host: 0.0.0.0** in *elasticsearch.yml*.

Could you please help me? And could you please explain, what exactly this code does?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/connecting.html), basically you need to use the below if you want to connect to Elasticsearch locally;

```
client = Elasticsearch("http://localhost:9200")
indexName = "art"
client.indices.create(index=indexName)
```

1. `client` tells where this instance needs to connect to to talk to  Elasticsearch
2. `indexName` is the name of the index you want to use
3. the last line is the action, what you want to do, ie create the index you defined

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain, what does every step does in this code?

Comment: just updated the post

Comment: could you please explain also the error "BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'resource_already_exists_exception', 'index [art/f6ZNy9CyRZatG2uEBA7tOg] already exists')" when I run the same thing. again.

Comment: you cannot create an index if one with the same name exists, you should delete it first if you want to recreate it